# Creating Stateful Modals with Angularjs and MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, materialize

I am trying to utilize the [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) Framework's `Modal` component along with Angularjs' `ui-router` module, but I'm having trouble trying to configure it properly.

Here's my `$stateProvider` definition

```
// Modal States ===============================
.state("modal", {
    views:{
      "modal": {
        templateUrl: "resources/templates/modal.html"
      }
    },
    abstract: true
})

.state("modal.modal1", {
    views:{
      "modal": {
        templateUrl: "resources/templates/modals/modal-content-1.html"
      }
    }
  })
```

And the `ui-view' definition on my index.html along with the trigger

```
<div ui-view="modal" autoscroll="false"></div>
```

What I'm trying to figure out is how to both render the modal and simultaneously switch to the `modal1` state using the trigger on the Materialize button.

The init of the modal is simple enough:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
<!-- Modal Structure -->
 <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the state config you wrote is not correct,  you have used the same named "modal" ui-view in both parent and child states.
Does your resources/templates/modal.html also contains a ui-view named "modal" ?

As your parent state is abstract, it can not be activated but for any child state to render, your parent state's template should have a ui-view.
Example below:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/contacts',

        // Note: abstract still needs a ui-view for its children to populate.
        // You can simply add it inline here.
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })
    .state('contacts.list', {
        // url will become '/contacts/list'
        url: '/list'
        //...more
    })
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        // url will become '/contacts/detail'
        url: '/detail',
        //...more
    })
```

Reference: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-&-nested-views#abstract-state-usage-examples